Babel configuration error with NativeWind set up 'nativewind is not a function'
I am trying to configure tailwind in my react native project but i keep getting this Babel error:
iOS Bundling failed 4839ms
error: pages/SignUp/SignUp.js: [BABEL] nativewind is not a function (While processing: babel.js")

This is my Babel.config.js:
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [["nativewind/babel", { mode: "transformOnly" }]],
};

This is my Package.json:
{
  "name": "themoneytree",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo-google-fonts/comfortaa": "^0.2.3",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "amqplib": "^0.5.2",
    "expo": "^49.0.23",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.0.3",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.5.4",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "node": "^18.20.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-css-interop": "^0.0.34",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^9.1.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-pie-chart": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
    "postcss": "^8.4.38",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


This is my tailwind.config.js file:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */

const nativewind = require("nativewind/tailwind/css")
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
module.exports = {
  // NOTE: Update this to include the paths to all of your component files.
  content: ["./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", 
  "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}", 
  "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  "./pages/**/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  presets: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        purple: {
          default: '#dba4eb',
          light: '#f5d0fe',
          dark: '#612057',
        },
        'midnight': {
          default:'#9866ea',
          light:'#58055a',
          dark: '#3c0764',
        },
        pink: {
        default: '#ea66cd',
        light: '#f77ce3',
        dark: '#bb2aa4',
        },

        fuchsia: {
          default: '#c026d3',
          light: '#f0abfc',
          dark: '#4a044e'
        },
        'dark': '#76199e',
        'soft-dark': '#2A2A2F', 
        'green': '#32a852',
        'white': '#f5f7f6',
      },
      spacing: {
        '2x': '20px',
        '3x': '30px',
      },
      borderRadius: {
        '4xl': '40px',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [nativewind()],
}

This is my postcss.config.js:
// postcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), [require("nativewind/postcss")]],
};


I have tried clearing the expo cache and have tried removing node modules and re-installing but i continue to get some sort of babel error.
